# How to debug Roblox programs written in Lua?

Tags: lua

```
 repeat
  io.write("Enter your guess : ")

  -- Gets input from the user
  guess = io.read()

  -- Either surround the number with quotes, or convert the string into
  -- a number
until tonumber(guess) == 15
```

I also tried replacing `io.read()` with `os.read()`but it didn't work, and I don't know why, because it worked for Derek. See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iMacxZQMPXs) at 20:46.

Comment: Please describe your problem in text. What happens when you run the code? What would you want to happen?

Comment: Your title should give a brief description of the problem you would like to solve. Such as `Getting user input using io.read() in roblox lua` if i understand your question correctly. and as Roland stated you need more substance in your question body

Comment: I'll updownvote when the title is amended - please ping me when it is done.

Comment: Roblox users should honestly stick to [ScriptingHelpers](http://scriptinghelpers.org)

Comment: I believe this question has been abandoned, I recommend voting to close. It is not clear what the problem is, or what has been tried to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing from your name you're using Roblox, not the Lua interpreter?
Modules `io` and `os` are not available in Robolox.

I guess you did not follow the youtube tutorial from the beginning.
Using a standard Lua distribution as shown in the first few minutes should cause no issues with the provided code.

Refer to [Roblox UserInputService](https://developer.roblox.com/api-reference/class/UserInputService) if you need user input in Roblox.